# Starting gestures in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have recently started learning React Native and have started to look into swiping and gestures etc.

However, every tutorial seems to use a different method whether it is with a PanResponder or the Animated library, or Reanimated, or React Native Gesture Handler or the gesture responder system. Its all starting to become overwhelming and stopping me from progressing

Could someone please lead me in the right direction with which ones are the most used and the best options to learn/ what use case certain ones have?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: PanResponder and the "gesture responder system" are both part of react-native-gesture-handler.  PanResponder is a good place to start for swiping and dragging things.

Comment: The same people that make react-native-gesture-handler also make Reanimated (Software Mansion). You'll often see them mentioned together for this reason. The Animated API is one of the React Native core modules and can be used without any external dependencies.